# Data type in the database for seasonal intervals

Tags: php, database, date, validation

Please tell me what type of data in the database would be more correct to use.

I need to define seasonal intervals within a year. For example: Low season (September 1 - November 15, February 1 - March 15) and Medium season (November 16 - December 20) and High season (December 21 - January 31). Apply them to each current year.

Create a seasons table:

id,
name,
start,
end,
price,
company_id

What is the best data type to use in a database: start and end?

Type Date: 2022-09-01 - 2022-11-15

Type Float: 09.01 - 11.15 (M.D - M.D

Type Integer: 901 - 1115 (901/100 = 9.01 (m.d) - 1115/100 = 11.15 (m.d))

Validation: When creating a record in the database, you need to check whether the periods overlap each other.

Comment: what you have tried for this?

Comment: I would recommend to store day and month in separate fields like start_day, start_month, end_day, end_month

Comment: I tried to do this, but then I have a problem how to check the periods month day - month day.